# How can I use AJAX with check-box categories?

Tags: categories, wp-query, ajax

How can I build a search filter ([something like this](http://tvpedia.org/gen/actiune)) with WordPress?

I have a custom post type name: "Locatii".  It is a custom post type with categories.

Ex: Cat 1 , Cat 2 ... and so on.

How can I implement AJAX so that when I click Cat 1 ( checkbox) and Cat 2 I should retrieve the posts that are in that categories, without having a search button.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to hook into the "onchange" event of javascript. When using jquery, it's as simple as `$('<the selector string>').change(function(){});`

When ever the values are changed, you'll do an AJAX request to the server with the new parameters & populate the output screen with the new result. For the server-side, you'll check the parameters, do some validations & send the response after reading the data from the database.

This codex article will help http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you give me more details PHP code or a link ... I am not a great connoisseur of Ajax language.

Comment: Please go through the link provided in the answer & then add to the question some code that you've tried so far

Comment: Ok, i will do that, i will come with an answer... thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest starting with the [Query Multiple Taxonomies](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/query-multiple-taxonomies/) plugin. As far as I know it doesn't use AJAX, but you could try to extend it to add AJAX support.

Comment: Answers should be [more than plain links](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). They should actually be an answer instead of a route where someone will _maybe find_ an answer. Please help preventing link rot, [edit] your answer and provide the needed information that helps the OP as well as later visitors to solve their problem.